# How Do You Make Python Turtle Stop Moving?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I've tried to do `turtle.speed(0)`, and I've tried `turtle.goto(turtle.xcor(), turtle.ycor())` nothing is seeming to work.

This Is The Code:

```
import turtle

def stopMovingTurtle():
    ## Here I Need To Stop The Turtle ##

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(stopMovingTurtle, 'Return')
turtle.goto(-200, 0)
turtle.goto(200, 0)
```

So how do I stop it?

Comment: `onkey` just binds a function to a key, so you have to `listen` afterwards for keys. switch `onkey` and `listen`

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't help my question.

Comment: Have you tried it? I gave the idea of switching the order of `turtle.listen()` and `turtle.onkey()` because `turtle.onkey` doesn't "do" anything other than bind a function to a key, but `listen` does.

Comment: I have done that, in my code I put print to confirm it and it does work, I just need to know how to stop the turtle moving...

Comment: try using both `.speed(0)` and `.goto` together

Comment: You could try `turtle.home()` to make it return home, `turtle.up()` to make it stop drawing.

Comment: I've got it, I just stamped it when pressing enter, then hid the turtle

Answer (score 1):

The problem here isn't the order of `turtle.listen()` vs. `turtle.onkey()`, it's that the key event isn't being processed until the current operation completes.  You can improve this by segmenting your long `turtle.goto(-200, 0)` motion into smaller motions, each of which allows a chance for your key event to act.  Here's a rough example:

```
import turtle

in_motion = False

def stopMovingTurtle():
    global in_motion
    in_motion = False

def go_segmented(t, x, y):
    global in_motion
    in_motion = True

    cx, cy = t.position()

    sx = (x > cx) - (x < cx)
    sy = (y > cy) - (y < cy)

    while (cx != x or cy != y) and in_motion:
        if cx != x:
            cx += sx
        if cy != y:
            cy += sy

        t.goto(cx, cy)

turtle.speed('slowest')
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(stopMovingTurtle, 'Return')

go_segmented(turtle, -200, 0)
go_segmented(turtle, 200, 0)

turtle.done()
```

If (switch to the window and) hit return, the turtle will stop drawing the current line.

Answer (score 1):

Just add turtle.done() at the end of your "Turtle code". With the same indentation as the turtle commands.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the speed 0? using `turtle.speed(0)`
If yes and for some reason it doesn't work you could also get the position
of the turtle like so: `turtle.position()` and then do a `while` loop that keeps it on the same position with a `goto`: `turtle.goto(its_position)`.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on this and I created this that works:

```
turtle.listen()
turtle.onkeypress(t.pu,'0') # i set it for 0 just because
```

this doesnt exactly stop the turtle, but it does stop the turtle from drawing more from the time you click.... It works for what I am using it for so thought I would share :)